# Using a regexp to match my string content?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I think I should use a regexp to match content in my file.

I want to replace all sequences of `w=<DIGIT>` e.g. what I want to achieve is many

```
s.replace('w=99923123','')
s.replace('w=23123','')
s.replace('w=123','')
```

So I wonder if you can suggest a regexp that matches my expression?

Update

I tried the obvious and it seems to work

```
>>> import re
>>> s='m=2&w=3'
>>> s=re.sub('w=\d', '', s)
>>> s
'm=2&'
```

Comment: I've now tried the obvious `s=re.sub('w=\d', '', s)` Thank you for saying that I ould do it

Comment: It only matches a single digit, though. Check Antti's answer.

Comment: what about s='m=2&w=32'?

Comment: add '+' to the end like 'w=\d+'

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It's enough to catch one occurence of w=<digit>. I actually am using it to redirect an url based on numeric ID to a friendly url based on name i.e. /<region>/? so I make a redirect using this regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
pat = re.compile('w=[0-9]+')  # or you can use \d+
s = pat.sub('', s)
```

---

### Update

Then you need to notice that if this is a more complex one, my regex matches tw=123 too,
and tw=123a456, but does not do what you want. Instead, maybe you should not use a regex at all (if you have a problem, and then use a regex, you now have 2 problems, they say). 
You can try this:

```
import urlparse
import urllib

s = 'w=123&q=456&tw=123&w=123abc&foo=bar&w=12'

# s here must be key=value&key=value only
parsed = urlparse.parse_qsl(s, keep_blank_values=True)
filtered = [ i for i in parsed if not (i[0] == 'w' and i[1].isdigit()) ]
s = urllib.urlencode(filtered)
```

notably it removes only those w=value pairs whose value consists only of digits.

Comment: Thank you. I accept both solutions since there will be only one occurence of w=digit in the string. I use it to make an url redirect from an id-based query string to a more readable url i.e. /<region>/? and I pass on the rest of the query string. I think it's a nice way to clean up a messy url to arrange parameters into directory grouping where everi w=digit becomes a unique /<region>/ and of course this won't work of two regions have the same name.